# Connect to SQL Server with Active Directory with MFA support

Tags: c#, sql-server

What should be the valid connection string to connect to `SQL Server` database as in subject. I am able to correctly login using `Management Studio` with option: `Active Directory with MFA support` then puttin`g username, servername and database` name then when clicking ok it ask for password. I was looking on internet but so far cannot found any solution.

Comment: The corresponding connection string option is `Authentication=Active Directory Interactive`. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/sql-database/active-directory-interactive-connect-azure-sql-db) for more.

Comment: @JeroenMostert tried that but doesnt work, could you post example connection string?

Comment: The link contains a [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/active-directory-interactive-connect-azure-sql-db#c-code-example) that actually builds a connection string (using `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`, although that's optional and you could just build the string yourself). (Do not copy that code's habit of using two-letter abbreviations for namespaces, though, that's just bad.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert i do not have Uri/ id .. for instance... I do have sql server database name, username, password, port